# Dependancy injection is making my code ugly

Tags: php, testing, dependency-injection, phpunit

For testability we use DI, however I have a problem. Anytime I want to call something 
my code now looks ugly.  I’m trying to understand how to avoid having to pass all the dependencies into a constructor, yet still maintain testability.

For example, lets imagine a service class to perform passport checks

```
Person < holds person data
PassportCheckService < enables us to perform check
PassportCheckRequest < holds params and any logic such as validation
PassportCheckSoapClient < php soap client with options specific to request
PassportCheckResponse < the response object
PersonDocumentService < save documents for a person
```

the class

```
class PassportCheckService {
    protected $person;
    protected $request;
    protected $response;
    protected $client;
    protected $personDocumentService;

    // constructor
    public function __construct(
        Person                  $person,
        PassportCheckRequest    $request,
        PassportCheckResponse   $response,
        PassportCheckSoapClient $client,
        PersonDocumentService   $personDocumentService
    ) {
        $this->person               = $person;
        $this->request                  = $request;
        $this->response                 = $response;
        $this->client                   = $client;
        $this->personDocumentService    = $personDocumentService;
    }

    // perform service
    public function execute() : PassportCheckResponse
    {
        // make call & build response instance
        $this->response->build($this->client->performCall($this->request));

        // save document
        if ($this->response->isSuccessStatus() &&
            $this->response->hasSavableDocument()
        ) {
            $this->personDocumentService->saveDocument(
                $this->person,
                $this->response->getDocumentFilename(),
                $this->response->getDocumentContents(),
                $this->response->getDocumentMime()
            );
        }

        // return response
        return $this->response;
    }
}
```

The problem is in order to call this service I have to pass in the dependancies:

```
$passportCheckService = new PassportCheckService(
    $person,
    $request,
    new PassportCheckResponse,
    new PassportCheckSoapClient,
    new PersonDocumentService
);

$passportCheckResponse = $passportCheckService->execute();
```

Imagine theres 5 more actions added to the service, now we need 5 more injections? 
Notice three of the dependancies passed in are just new instances.

Where am I going wrong here?

Many thanks.

Comment: If your classes have that many dependencies, my initial thought would be that it's doing too much. Next thoughts would be that it looks like things can be grouped, e.g. you could have a PassportCheck factory to create your Response and SoapClient objects, so you'd just have a dependency on the factory.

Comment: So would I define the factory first, passing in the response and soap client objects. Then on the next line define the service, passing in the instance built with the factory?

Comment: well presumably, the factory would deal with creating the soap+repsonse object, so I wouldn't need to pass anything to it. If thats the case, how can I then replicate the factory in testing? Since the objects in the factory are then hardcoded? Correct me if I'm wrong here.

Comment: That is entirely up to you. I'm only making a possible suggestion. Whether it's right / best comes down to you and your project (i.e. matter of opinion). If you haven't already, it may be worth looking up the various well-known design patterns. Might also be worth looking at other projects on github and alike to see how others have done it, and frameworks too. Wrt your test question, assuming unit tests, the dependencies should ideally be mocks, so what they return is up to you.

Comment: IMO, `PersonDocumentService` is the only dependency that should be injected during object instantiation, the other items look like run-time data and should be passed in as parameters of the method `execute`. Also, by injecting the run-time data into the constructor you're forcing the object to be single use ...

Comment: @JonStirling thank you, appreciate the help, makes things clear to understand.

Comment: @qujck great point - when I inject the run time objects to execute function, do you recommend using a factory? What is your approach to avoid too many dependancy injections in this case?

Comment: I'm not a user of PHP so can only offer generic opinions. I try to limit what each object does, tending towards a larger number of small specific service classes rather than a few large ones. Dependent services are always passed in via the constructor and run-time data as parameters to the method being called. I'm not sure what purpose the factory would serve. If your data objects don't have any behaviour it's safe to new them up anywhere.